# Continuity, preimage of an open set of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm stuck trying to find the error in the following:

. $\mathbb{R}^{2*} = \Bbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\} $ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

. Let $f := (\rho, \theta) \in\ U = \ (0,+\infty) \times (-\pi, \pi] \ \to (\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta) \in \ \mathbb{R}^{2*}$ the canonical polar projection. This application appears to be continuous, being the result of various operations over continuous applications.

. $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{2*}) = U$ which would tend to prove that $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$...

Obviously something is wrong somewhere. :)

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I'm French, originally, and I'm not proficient at speaking math in English. Don't hesitate telling me if I'm not saying things the right way, it can only help me get better. :)

Comment: In english one writes $(0, +\infty)\times (-\pi, \pi]$ !

Comment: @Gribouillis I’m French too... nobody is perfect. If I’m not misleading, you would even write $(0, \infty)\times (-\pi, \pi]$ in English.

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks for the tip, i'll use that notation next time :) Anyways it's actually much more readable (though confusing when talking of open intervals between finite values: is (1,2) an open ball or a point of R^2?)

Comment: The flaw in your proof is that $f$ is only defined on $U$, so you're proving that $U$ is open in $U$, which is always true.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is really bad. You should just say "$f\colon U\to {\mathbb R}^{2*}$ is defined by $f(\rho,\theta)=(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)$".

Comment: @tomasz, thanks, yes you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour Nash,

$f$ is not defined on $\mathbb R^2$ but on $U$. You’re right that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{2*}) = U$. Which is not a contradiction because $U$ is indeed an open set OF $U$. You have to consider relative topology here.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense! I need to learn more about relative topology in subsets of metric spaces. Thanks @mathcounterexamples.net and @Gribouillis! :)

Comment: @NashLam Tu es bienvenu mon ami!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net "de rien" is de proper expression :)